# Allow Discussion For Requirements

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have only been using Stack Overflow for a month, and I would like to make a suggestion.

What if we allow users to post questions that ask for requirements?

Suppose a user is asked something by their client and is not really sure how to achieve their objective, and hopes that someone can give them advice not only at the high level, but also at the lower, less abstract level.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for technical coding questions, **period.**

Comment: I'm not sure what you're requesting here.  It _sounds_ like you're talking about allow people to ask questions on "how to do something?"  That's already allowed (though requiring a lot more research effort by the community).

Comment: He's asking if he can crowd-source his job, basically.

Comment: Looks like a big 10-10, good buddy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [value of Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/about) is in the experts who take their time to answer your questions. We don't want to waste their time, because if you do that too often, they get annoyed and leave. And then we have nothing and people starting complaining about how this is why we can't have nice things.

What you're asking for is *tedious* on a Q&A platform: allow people who have done very little research and aren't even sure about what they want to ask questions of experts with the expectation that said experts will stick around and tease out all the details about what the user wants to do so they can then explain it in high-level (followed by low-level) terms.

To me, that sounds like a great way to *drive away* experts, not attract them.

Stack Exchange simply can't be everything to everyone, and what you're looking for is a mentor or a consultant, not a Q&A site. I'm sure there are plenty of sites and services out there (if you're in school, speak with your careers or guidance counselor) that can provide that level of in-depth service to you and others.